# How to css select all divs to levels down from div with ID

Tags: html, css

I think I'm just spacing this one out but here's the html structure. I'm trying to select the five divs nested two deep from the id'ed div in a dynamically generated page.

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <div class="class1">
        <div class="myclass">stuff</div>
        <div class="myclass">stuff</div>
        <div class="myclass">stuff</div>
        <div class="myclass">stuff</div>
        <div class="myclass">stuff</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to adjust the css of all the "myclass" divs using a css selector and my custom css overriding the dynamically generated jQuery Mobile css class.

Thanks!

Comment: I simplified the generated code which gave the divs multiple classes. However, the #mydiv > div > div worked. Stupid me I was trying to use #mydiv + div + div. Sigh. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to overwrite styles with this selector:

```css
#mydiv > .class1 > .myclass { ... }
```